# Wagtail i18n confusion

Tags: django, internationalization, wagtail

I've hooked up my site for internationalization as described here: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/i18n.html#enabling-locale-management

My issue is, there doesn't seem to be anywhere that describes how the following works

"It records which pages are translations of each other using a shared UUID stored in the translation_key field"

Is this automatic? If so, how does it work out what is a translation of what? If not automatic, how do I set a page as a translation of another?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to have been my mistake. Quite well hidden in the documents is an instruction to add the simple_translation app. Which feels like it should be in the initial setup instructions.